# how to prevent scientific notation with doubles in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

How can I prevent scientific notation when setting a UITextfield text value from a double variable?
I've tried formatting it with "%f", but then it displays -0 as -0.00000. Formatting with "%g" makes it show the exponent.

Answer (score 3):

```
%.0f
```

Meaning a float with 0 fractional digits.

**Edit**

As it seems you still need some precision, you should use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance, which is much more flexible.

You can use the [`-setMinimumFractionDigits:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits%3a) and [`-setMaximumFractionDigits:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits%3a), so zero will be `0`, but you'll still be able to have precision:

```
NSNumberFormatter * fmt;

fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter new ] autorelease ];

[ fmt setMinimumFractionDigits: 0 ];
[ fmt setMaximumFractionDigits: 2 ];
[ fmt setMinimumIntegerDigits:  1 ];

NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: ( float )0 ] ] );
NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: ( float )0.42 ] ] );
```

Comment: I still need to show some decimal precision. Truncating the fraction doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: thanks, following your suggestion I used NSNumberFormatter in a slightly different way (again, i'm not trying to limit the precision).
<code>
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
myTextField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.myDoubleValue]];
</code>

Now I'm trying to find out how to do the reverse conversion. From a string like 2,000,000.45 to a double.(do I have to create my own method to remove the formatting or is there an existing method in cocoa?)
Thanks for the help

Comment: For the reverse operation, best is to use a [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: But if your text is already inside a NSControl, you can also simply use `doubeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of decimal places in the format string:

```
%.0f
```

will round to whole numbers,

```
%.1f
```

will round to 1 decimal, etc., printing -0 as `-0` or `-0.0`, respectively.

Comment: I still need to keep decimal precision, but clean unnecessary 0's on the right, the '-' if the value is 0, and the '.' if there is no fraction